# How to solve a nonlinear SDE analytically

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a numerical solution for the following equation: x'(t)= x(t) - x^3(t) + n(t) where n(t) is a white gaussian noise with zero mean and unit variance. I am a bit confused on how to go about the solution analytically. How do I deal with this problem?